# r propensity score matching (psm) for the same year

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I am conducting PSM for my study. 
I used MatchIt package for my PSM.
And the result gave me a similar set of control groups, but they control groups were different from the treatment group in terms of year.
For example, my psm from the package gave me like this

```
Firm year psm_variables treated
 A   2013     0.425        1
 B   1996     0.421        0
```

I want to get a control group in the same year for the treatment group.
Any suggestion for this case?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can perform exact matching on year. In `matchit()`, just set `exact = "year"`. This will ensure that the matching occurs within each year. You should still include `year` in the propensity score model (i.e., the formula in `matchit()`) as a factor variable. Note that this might cause you to lose some treated units that can't find matches in the same year.